# Need GRPC calls to Thanos Sidecar to test if the system is working

Tags: prometheus, grpc, thanos, grpcurl

I am trying to debug connectivity issues with Thanos Sidecar.
I have Prometheus & Sidecar set up on a rack. On another rack I have Thanos Query to query the remote Sidecar. Actually I have about 30 remote racks. The query works to some racks some times and they come and go from the list of available query endpoints. Often they seem to timeout eg. context deadline exceeded.
I am able to use `grpcurl <rack-url>:10901 grpc.health.v1.Health.Check` to check the endpoints and I get status SERVING. However I can't figure out how to get more data. `grpcurl <rack-url>:10901 list` returns

```
grpc.health.v1.Health
grpc.reflection.v1alpha.ServerReflection
thanos.Exemplars
thanos.Metadata
thanos.Rules
thanos.Store
thanos.Targets
thanos.info.Info
```

However if I try to list more on any of the thanos categories, I get Symbol not found

```
grpcurl <rack-url>:10901 list thanos.info.Info
Failed to list methods for service "thanos.info.Info": Symbol not found: thanos.info.Info
```

My question is, What grpcurl call can I do that replicates what Thanos Query is sending when Query is trying to get information to add the Sidecar to the list of available endpoints?

Thanks

Also any good resources on how grpc works with Thanos/Prometheus queries would be appreciated.

Comment: See [Reflection issues](https://github.com/fullstorydev/grpcurl/issues/22) for a possible explanation of the inability to reflect `thanos.info.Info`.

Answer (score 0):

```
grpcurl -insecure -import-path=protobuf -import-path=thanos/pkg/ -proto=store/storepb/rpc.proto thanos-sidecar:443 thanos.Store/Info
```

You can find those files (import-path) in thanos's github repo depending on your version : https://github.com/thanos-io/thanos